# How to get underlying constant type from singleton type with Scala reflection API

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros, scala-reflect

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val a: 42 = 42
val t: Type = typeOf[a.type]
assert(getConstantType(t).get =:= typeOf[42])

def getConstantType(t: Type): Option[ConstantType] = ???
```

How could I generally implement `getConstantType` so that the above assertion passes?
I assumed that something like this was possible since the assertion below passes:

```
assert(t <:< typeOf[42])
```

`t.widen` goes too far as it return `Int`. I'm looking for something that returns `Int(42)`.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
assert(t.resultType =:= typeOf[42])
```

Updated -

```
def getConstantType[T](t: T): t.type = t
```

Update 2 -

```
def getConstantType(tp: Type): Option[ConstantType] = {
  tp.erasure match {
    case ConstantType(_) => Some(tp.erasure.asInstanceOf[ConstantType])
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Comment: That does pass the assertion, but for my use case I need to get a `ConstantType` from `t`, so I really am looking for an implementation of `getConstantType`.

Comment: Updated for getConstantType

Comment: Your updated `getConstantType` method doesn't return a value of type `ConstantType` as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
def getConstantType(tp: Type): Option[ConstantType] = {
  def unrefine(t: Type): Type = t.dealias match {
    case RefinedType(List(t), scope) if scope.isEmpty => unrefine(t)
    case t                                            => t
  }

  unrefine(tp) match {
    case SingleType(_, sym) => sym.typeSignature match {
      case NullaryMethodType(t) => unrefine(t) match {
        case c: ConstantType => Some(c)
        case _               => None
      }
      case _                 => None
    }
    case _                   => None
  }
}
```